# Regex for combination of at least one alphanumeric and special character

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, regex

I need to create a regex which contains at least 1 special character, and at least 1 number with alphabets.

Comment: Could please give example strings, which should be matched by your regex ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following pattern:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])(?=.*[A-Za-z]).*$
```

Explanation:

```
(?=.*[0-9])          assert one number present
(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9])   assert one special character present
(?=.*[A-Za-z])       assert one alpha present
```

Note that I have defined a special character as being anything not alphanumeric.  If instead you have a list of special characters, then you can modify the middle lookahead in my pattern.

Comment: If special characters are a smaller list I think you'll need to change the final `.*` as well to avoid invalid matches.